# .NET 5.0 Webjob no longer starting with self-contained build

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I switched my builds to self-contained because of .NET 5.0. I know there is a preview runtime, but I don't want to bet on this for my production environment. I encountered situations where the preview runtime was switched back unintentionally (e.g. scale-out).

```
dotnet publish --configuration release --self-contained true --runtime win-x64
```

After doing a self-contained build, my webjob no longer started. While looking at the logs, I just found this:

```
[12/22/2020 16:36:05 > 62427f: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[12/22/2020 16:36:05 > 62427f: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[12/22/2020 16:36:05 > 62427f: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[12/22/2020 16:36:07 > 62427f: SYS INFO] Run script 'createdump.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[12/22/2020 16:36:07 > 62427f: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ] createdump [options] pid
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ] -f, --name - dump path and file name. The default is '%TEMP%\dump.%p.dmp'. These specifiers are substituted with following values:
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ]    %p  PID of dumped process.
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ]    %e  The process executable filename.
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ]    %h  Hostname return by gethostname().
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ]    %t  Time of dump, expressed as seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ] -n, --normal - create minidump.
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ] -h, --withheap - create minidump with heap (default).
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ] -t, --triage - create triage minidump.
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ] -u, --full - create full core dump.
[12/22/2020 16:36:35 > 62427f: ERR ] -d, --diag - enable diagnostic messages.
[12/22/2020 16:36:36 > 62427f: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1
[12/22/2020 16:36:36 > 62427f: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[12/22/2020 16:36:36 > 62427f: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

What does this createdump log output mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When doing a self-contained build, your build output folder will include a `createdump.exe` file. When deploying the WebJob to App Service, it will now pick this .exe instead of your WebJob. This is why the log shows the CLI output of createdump.exe.

The fix: **create a `run.cmd` file that contains only the name of your `mywebjob.exe`.**

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs

> - Per file type we look first for a file named: run.{file type extension} (for example run.cmd or run.exe).
> - If it doesn't exists for all file types, we'll then look for the first file with a supported file type extension.
> - The order of file types extension used is: .cmd, .bat, .exe, .ps1, .sh, .php, .py, .js.
> - The recommended script file to have in your job directory is: run.cmd.
> - Note: We'll only look for a script under the root directory of that job (not under sub directories of it).
> - Note: make sure .bat/.cmd files don't include the UTF-8 BOM (inserted by some editors such as Visual Studio by default), which can break things!

PS: You cannot simply delete the createdump.exe, because your app will [not start without it](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43716). Edit: you can now delete the file if you use net6 or later.

Comment: This also happens to appear when publishing a non-self-contained application.
Also simply deleting the `createdump.exe` works as well now.